# Error: Request failed with status code 404 , Axios trying to fetch github user emails using passport-github2

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, passport-github2

```
const Raven = require('raven')
const GithubStrategy = require('passport-github2').Strategy
const axios = require('axios');
const models = require('../../../db/models').models

const config = require('../../../../config')
const secrets = config.SECRETS
const debug = require('debug')('oauth:strategies:github')
const { generateReferralCode } = require('../../../utils/referral')

/**
 * Authenticate _users_ using their Github Accounts
 */

module.exports = new GithubStrategy({
    clientID: secrets.GITHUB_CONSUMER_KEY,
    clientSecret: secrets.GITHUB_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: config.SERVER_URL + config.GITHUB_CALLBACK,
    passReqToCallback: true,
}, async function (req, token, tokenSecret, profile, cb) {
    let profileJson = profile._json
    console.log(profileJson);
    
    try{
       const config = {method:'get',headers:{'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`}};
       const result = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/user/emails',config);
       let emailArr = result.data;
           let primaryGithubEmail = emailArr.filter((email)=>{return email.primary;});
       profileJson.email = primaryGithubEmail[0].email;
    }catch(error){
       console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('======== profile after request ============');
    console.log(profileJson);
    console.log('====================');
    let oldUser = req.user

    Raven.setContext({ extra: { file: 'githubstrategy' } })
    try {
        if (oldUser) {
            debug('User exists, is connecting Github account')
            /*
            This means an already logged in users is trying to
            connect Github to his account. Let us see if there
            are any connections to his Github already
            */

            const ghaccount = await models.UserGithub.findOne({ where: { id: profileJson.id } })
            if (ghaccount) {
                throw new Error('Your Github account is already linked with codingblocks account Id: ' + ghaccount.get('userId'))
            } else {
                await models.UserGithub.upsert({
                    id: profileJson.id,
                    token: token,
                    tokenSecret: tokenSecret,
                    username: profileJson.login,
                    userId: oldUser.id
                })

                const user = await models.User.findById(oldUser.id)

                if (user) {
                    return cb(null, user.get())
                } else {
                    return cb(null, false, { message: "Could not retrieve existing Github linked account" })
                }
            }
        } else {
            /*
            This means either -
                a. This is a new signup via Github
                b. Someone is trying to login via Github
             */
            let userGithub = await models.UserGithub.findOne({
                include: [models.User],
                where: { id: profileJson.id }
            })
            /*
            If userGithub exists then
            Case (a): login
             */
            if (!userGithub) {

                /*
                    If there is any user with verified email equal to the email comming from github strategy , then create a new entry in userGithub table and login that user
                    */
                const userWithVerifiedEmail = await models.User.findOne({
                    where: {
                        verifiedemail: profileJson.email
                    }
                })
                if (userWithVerifiedEmail) {
                    userGithub = await models.UserGithub.create({
                        id: profileJson.id,
                        token: token,
                        tokenSecret: tokenSecret,
                        username: profileJson.login,
                        userId: userWithVerifiedEmail.get('id'),
                    })

                    return cb(null, userWithVerifiedEmail.get());

                }

                /*
                Case (b): New Signup
                First ensure there aren't already users with the same email
                id that comes from Github
                 */
                let existingUsers = [];
                if (profileJson.email) {
                    existingUsers = await models.User.findAll({
                        include: [{
                            model: models.UserGithub,
                            attributes: ['id'],
                            required: false
                        }],
                        where: {
                            email: profileJson.email,
                            '$usergithub.id$': { $eq: null }
                        }
                    })
                }

                if (existingUsers && existingUsers.length > 0) {
                    let oldIds = existingUsers.map(eu => eu.id).join(',')
                    return cb(null, false, {
                        message: `
                    Your email id "${profileJson.email}" is already used in the following Coding Blocks Account(s):
                    [ ${oldIds} ]
                    Please log into your old account and connect Github in it instead.
                    Use 'Forgot Password' option if you do not remember password of old account`
                    })
                }


                /* Check if users with same username exist. Modify username accordingly */

                const existCount = await models.User.count({ where: { username: profileJson.login } })

                userGithub = await models.UserGithub.create({
                    id: profileJson.id,
                    token: token,
                    tokenSecret: tokenSecret,
                    username: profileJson.login,
                    user: {
                        username: existCount === 0 ? profileJson.login : profileJson.login + "-gh",
                        firstname: profileJson.name ? profileJson.name.split(' ')[0] : profileJson.login,
                        email: profileJson.email,
                        referralCode: generateReferralCode(profileJson.email).toUpperCase(),
                        photo: profileJson.avatar_url,
                        verifiedemail: profileJson.email,
                        marketing_meta: req.session.marketingMeta
                    }
                }, {
                    include: [models.User],
                })
                req.visitor.event({
                    ea: 'successful',
                    ec: 'signup',
                    el: 'github'
                }).send()

                req.session.isNewSignup = true

                if (!userGithub) {
                    return cb(null, false, { message: 'Authentication Failed' })
                }

            }
            return cb(null, userGithub.user.get())
        }
    } catch (err) {
        Raven.captureException(err)
        cb(null, false, { message: err.message })
    }

})
```

when I am running this code locally on my system , its working fine , but as soon as I am sending the code to the staging and production i am getting the error

```
{ Error: Request failed with status code 404
0|oneauth  |     at createError (/home/codingblocks/servers/khaate/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
0|oneauth  |     at settle (/home/codingblocks/servers/khaate/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
0|oneauth  |     at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/codingblocks/servers/khaate/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
0|oneauth  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
0|oneauth  |     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
0|oneauth  |     at IncomingMessage.wrapped (/home/codingblocks/servers/khaate/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer/index.js:188:22)
...............
```

I am not able to understand why this error is comming and I am also not able to get the user emails , but locally this code works fine and I am able to fetch all the emails associated with the github of the user.